# Cant click on button | Selenium on WordPress Python 2.7

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Web Driver with Python,
and for some reason there is a button I can't click on.

**The button is the browse button on WordPress File Uploads.**

I have written a script using AutoIT to handle the file dialog, so I just need to click on a HTML button to launch the dialog and from there on *os.startfile(script.exe)* would do the rest.

Here is my code:

```
print 'find button'
browseButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#plupload-browse-button')
browseButton.click()
time.sleep(5)
print "AutoIT runs here"
```

And the error:

```
Error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

(fully seen in the attached picture)

P.S: The code gets there for sure, It prints the line before crashing, I even gave a 30 seconds delay before it gets to the crashing line so everything would be loaded up for 200%.
Please help =)
[image]
Best regards, thanks in advance to everyone
-CodingCode.

Comment: Please provide some of the markup.

Comment: Please provide us DOM.

Comment: If you use the `Dev Tools` in your browser, can you find the element by its ID? You can try to run in `Dev Tools -> Console (tab)`  the command `document.querySelectorAll("#plupload-browse-button")` and see if it's found. Another possibility is to have this inside another `frame/iframe`, but I'm not sure then if it could be found.

Comment: When typing document.querySelectorAll("#plupload-browse-button") it returns `[input#plupload-browse-button.button]`

Comment: I cant provide the whole file because its a PHP file based on lots of scripts, but here's the selector: #plupload-browse-button
XPath: //*[@id="plupload-browse-button"]
and outer html: <input id="plupload-browse-button" type="button" value="בחירת קבצים" class="button" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">

Comment: Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There could be few things, some has already been mentioned in the comments so not repeating it here.

but if it's not inside a frame and xpath is correct. you could use explicit wait.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) 
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'plupload-browse-button')))
elem.click()
```